# Show that B is a Boolean subalgebra of $\mathbb{P(N)}$ which cannot be Boolean isomorphic to some $\mathbb{P(M)}$

Tags: boolean-algebra

Let $B = \{X \subseteq \mathbb{N} | X  $
is finite or its complement
$ \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is finite$\}$. Show that
B is a Boolean subalgebra of $\mathbb{P(N)}$ which cannot be Boolean isomorphic to
some $\mathbb{P(M)}$.

Answer (score 2):

You should show yourself that it is a Boolean algebra. $B$ cannot be Boolean isomorphic to the power set of some set because the former is countably infinite and the latter is either finite of uncountable.